# Python Telegram Game Bot function error at 0x7fcfa257f790

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm a newbie in Python and recently tried my luck setting up a bot (**as you do...**) made by Mark Powers called [Telegram Arcade](https://github.com/Mark-Powers/telegram-arcade)

As it was evident, it was built with python-telegram-bot framework. Even though it looked simple to set it up (with included instructions) I can't get it to work.

Even after I updated some of the code to be in line with the changes to the framework, now i get an error that is displayed along with the user that is interacting with the bot: **function error at 0x7fcfa257f790** .

The code as of right now is as follows:

```
import configparser, threading, requests, json, re, time, sys

from uuid import uuid4

from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import InlineQueryResultGame, ParseMode, InputTextMessageContent
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import CallbackContext

from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


class Global:
    def __init__(self):
        return

class GameHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args)

    def do_GET(self):
        if "#" in self.path:
            self.path = self.path.split("#")[0]
        if "?" in self.path:
            (route, params) = self.path.split("?")
        else:
            route = self.path
            params = ""
        route = route[1:]
        params = params.split("&")
        if route in Global.games:
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(open(route+'.html', 'rb').read())
        elif route == "setScore":
            params = {}
            for item in self.path.split("?")[1].split("&"):
                if "=" in item:
                    pair = item.split("=")
                    params[pair[0]] = pair[1]
            print(params)
            if "imid" in params:
                Global.bot.set_game_score(params["uid"], params["score"], inline_message_id=params["imid"]) 
            else:
                Global.bot.set_game_score(params["uid"], params["score"], message_id=params["mid"], chat_id=params["cid"])
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'Set score')
        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'Invalid game!')

def start(update, context):
    bot.send_game(update.message.chat_id, Global.featured)

def error(update, context):
    print(update, error)

def button(update, context):
    print(update)
    query = update.callback_query
    game = query.game_short_name
    uid = str(query.from_user.id)
    if query.message:
        mid = str(query.message.message_id)
        cid = str(query.message.chat.id)
        url = "http://" + Global.host + ":"+Global.port + "/" + game + "?uid="+uid+"&mid="+mid+"&cid="+cid
    else:
        imid = update.callback_query.inline_message_id
        url = "http://" + Global.host + ":"+Global.port + "/" + game + "?uid="+uid+"&imid="+imid
    print(url)
    bot.answer_callback_query(query.id, text=game, url=url)

def inlinequery(update, context):
    query = context.inline_query.query
    results = []
    for game in Global.games:
        if query.lower() in game.lower():
            results.append(InlineQueryResultGame(id=str(uuid4()),game_short_name=game))
    context.inline_query.answer(results)
def main():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    token = config['DEFAULT']['API_KEY']
    Global.games = config['DEFAULT']['GAMES'].split(',')
    Global.host = config['DEFAULT']['HOST']
    Global.port = config['DEFAULT']['PORT']
    Global.featured = config['DEFAULT']['FEATURED']
    updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(InlineQueryHandler(inlinequery))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    updater.dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)
    Global.bot = updater.bot

    print("Polling telegram")
    updater.start_polling()

    print("Starting http server")   
    http = HTTPServer((Global.host, int(Global.port)), GameHTTPRequestHandler)
    http.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have been reading the documentarion and studying the examples and I can't seem to find the solution to this. Even inlineCommands are not working displaying a similar error. I would very much appreciate any advice and I'm sorry for not being an expert explaining my situation.. **Thank you!**

Comment: That's not an error: it's the string representation of the function `error`. You're passing `error` to the `print` call inside it, thus the message.

Comment: @enzo Oh.. I see... nvm then... Still can't figure why it isn't working...

Comment: Additionally: When I try to run the code "as is" in the original git, I get the following error:  

 `File "main.py", line 52, in start
    bot.send_game(update.message.chat_id, Global.featured)
AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'send_game' `

Comment: Does changing `bot.send_game` to `Global.bot.send_game` work?

Comment: Also, the signature of your `start` function does not match with the signature of the [original `start` function](https://github.com/Mark-Powers/telegram-arcade/blob/master/bot.py#L51). Does it fix when you change it?

Comment: @enzo Yes... Yes it does... Even tough it's not my code, just understanding it and seeing it work... ;_; Thank you! I'll try to solve the in_line problem now that the start is working!

Comment: What's the error that's showing with the inline commands?

Comment: @enzo It's giving me a similar message as before I would assume the same "fix" would work?

  ` File "main.py", line 73, in inlinequery
    query = context.inline_query.query
AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'inline_query' `

Comment: The [original code](https://github.com/Mark-Powers/telegram-arcade/blob/master/bot.py#L88) doesn't use `use_context=True` when creating the updater. Can you check it to see if it works?

Comment: @enzo I added it earlier when reading the documentation, no luck.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`python-telegram-bot` changed how callbacks work in v12, which was released two  years ago. The repo you're using seems to still work with the old callbacks. I recommend to first try & get it to work with ptb version 11.1. or 12.0 *without* passing `use_context=True` (in v12 this still defaults to `False` for backwards compatibility). If that works fine and you want to upgrade to newer `python-telegram-bot` versions, I highly recommend reading the transition guides for [v12](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0) and [v13](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-13.0).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be reading the transition guides! As for my problem, it seems that sometimes `context.` is not working as intended. After the correction notice from @enzo , I looked into the transition guide and upgraded accondigly, but I still couldn't put inline to work, until I reverted to this:

`def inlinequery(update, context):
 query = update.inline_query.query
 results = []
 for game in Global.games:
  if query.lower() in game.lower():
   results.append(InlineQueryResultGame(id=str(uuid4()),game_short_name=game))
 update.inline_query.answer(results)`

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The `update` parameter is the incoming update that the Bot API server sent - in this case it contains the inline query. the `context` parameter contains "only" convenience stuff that ties in with the PTB setup. that's why you can't expect `context` to have an `inline_query` attribute ;)